# Inserting text from text file into MySQL TEXT column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying the following which is not working:

```
update table_name set text_column= load_file('C:\temp\texttoinset.txt') where primary_key=5;
```

Here text_column is of type TEXT.

This gives:

```
Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it uses a system function that may return a different value on the slave. Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1
```

What is the right way to insert a log file contents in my SQL from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/316691/mysql-binlog-format-dilemma

Anyway, the key is **Statement is unsafe because it uses a system function that may return a different value on the slave.**

When the MySQL database is setup to use replication, system functions like `load_file` can cause issues.  The file `C:\temp\texttoinset.txt` is likely different between the master server and the slave server (or may not even exist on one of them).

When using replication, it is best to avoid system functions (like `load_file` and `NOW()`) because the values will be different when executed on different servers.  If you want to load a file into a MySQL database that uses replication, consider using PHP's [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to read the file, and then use that to insert it into the database.

As a side note, I don't know why you're trying to insert a log file into MySQL, especially as a single TEXT column.  There is probably a better way to do what you are wanting to do.